# Compatibility issue between AES encrypt in cryptojs and decrypt in python Crypto.Cipher

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, cryptojs, pycrypto

I'm trying to decrypt the password encrypted in js using cryptojs. But decryption in Python is failing.

JS code:

```
encryption(){
    var passwordString = "test@597";  //password from UI
     var cryptoKey = "1234567891234567";
     var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
     var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
     const key = this.generateKey(salt, cryptoKey);
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(passwordString, key,
    {
        iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv)
    });
    const ciphertext = encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
     const aesPassword = (iv + "::" + salt + "::" + ciphertext);
    console.log(aesPassword);
    console.log("CryptoJS.en",CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(aesPassword))); //need to send to api
   return CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(aesPassword));
  }
  generateKey(salt:any, cryptoKey:any) {
    return CryptoJS.PBKDF2(
      cryptoKey, 
      CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(salt)

,
      { keySize: this.keySize, iterations: this.iterationCount });
  }
```

Decryption code in Python:

The encrypted data is in this form "iv::salt::ciphertext".

```
>>> import base64
>>> import hashlib

>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> import os
# Below is the encrypted key generated from js code
>>> enc = 'NzVkMzZhNThkZDUzY2M5NjZmMWFkYzBkOTMwZDgwY2M6OjAxM2NjMTQ1YTMzYTYzNDgxZDdjNmFhZTE4ZmI4MGZiOjpTVXc4Z0g2ZUhGamxzSlhsc3JqL2FBPT0='
>>> iv =(base64.b64decode(enc).decode('utf-8')).split("::")[0]
>>> salt =(base64.b64decode(enc).decode('utf-8')).split("::")[1]
>>> enc =(base64.b64decode(enc).decode('utf-8')).split("::")[2]
>>> salt=bytes.fromhex(salt)

>>> iv=bytes.fromhex(iv)
>>> password='1234567891234567'
>>> private_key = hashlib.scrypt(password.encode(), salt=salt, n=2**14, r=8, p=1, dklen=32)
>>> cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
>>> cipher
<Crypto.Cipher._mode_cbc.CbcMode object at 0x7f271e3ca710>
>>> decrypted = cipher.decrypt(enc.encode())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_cbc.py", line 210, in decrypt
    raise ValueError("Data must be padded to %d byte boundary in CBC mode" % self.block_size)
ValueError: Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode
```

I have tried with padding in js as well but still decryption is not working:

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(passwordString, key,
    {
        iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv),
       padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
    });
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: In the CryptoJS code _PBKDF2_ is used, in the Python code _scrypt_. This generates different keys.

Comment: Also, the _actual_ ciphertext is Base64 encoded twice in the CryptoJS code, but only once in the PyCryptodome code. And PyCryptodome does not unpad _automatically_.

Comment: Hi @Topaco, I have tried with PBKDF2 as well but still it didn't work. This is how I tried
PBKDF2(password.encode(), salt, 32, 128)

Comment: I believe unpadding is done after it is decrypted but I'm getting error at cipher.decrypt()

Comment: _This is how I tried PBKDF2(password.encode(), salt, 32, 128)_: Since you didn't share `this.keySize` nor `this.iterationCount`, there is nothing there to compare! Possibly incorrectly specified key size (CryptoJS specifies as multiples of `WordArray`s (4 bytes), PyCryptodome in bytes), digest is probably OK as both use SHA-1 by default.

Comment: However, unless you fix the Base64 encoding inconsistency, it won't work. _I believe unpadding is done after it is decrypted_: Nope, not with PyCryptodome. Check the [padding module](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#crypto-util-padding-module).

Comment: The keysize is 128 and iteration count is 1000. If I try this way in python PBKDF2(password.encode(), salt, 128, 1000) it generates a key with 128 length but it fails with "ValueError: Incorrect AES key length (128 bytes)".

Comment: I didn't understand, how do I fix the Base64 encoding inconsistency ?? 
I checked the padding module, there also they are unpadding the decrypted data
"pt = unpad(cipher2.decrypt(ct), 16)".